# Vinelab/NeoEloquent Error While Integrating in Laravel

Tags: laravel, neo4j

I went to GitHub and tried to integrate Neo4J in Laravel but the problem is i get error while integrating in laravel. First problem is while adding in service provider:-
[image]

I think it is missing ::class and further while i prefer migration it says error while running composee dump autoload:
[image]

Please tell me how can i fix this! Please please please help me!

Comment: Extend providers array in same manner: without quotes adding with sufix: `Vinelab\NeoEloquent\NeoEloquentServiceProvider::class,`.

Comment: And what about migration? It doesn't work